# Correctly using of dependency injected DbContext to query Database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have set up my own context using (as I believe is correct):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContextPool<JobTrackingContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connection));
    services.AddScoped<IJobRepository, JobRepository>();
}
```

Then I define my `JobTrackingContext` as follows:

```
public JobTrackingContext(DbContextOptions<JobTrackingContext> options)
            : base(options)
{
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can define a repository to actually create/edit/delete Jobs:

```
 public class JobRepository : GenericRepository<Job, long>, IJobRepository
{
        private Job currentJob;
        public JobRepository(JobTrackingContext jobTrackingContext, JobTrackingSettings settings)
        : base(jobTrackingContext)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
        public async Task StartSync(JobType jobType, JobTriggerType jobTriggerType)
        {
            var tempJob = new Job(jobType, jobTriggerType);
            await _dbContext.Jobs.AddAsync(tempJob);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
}
```

And all this code gets instantiated by a Post-request to this API:

```
public async void Post()
{
    _logger.LogDebug("Going to start account sync");
    await _jobRepository.StartSync(JobType.ZRequestSync, JobTriggerType.Scheduled);
    try
    {
        await _sync.StartAsync();
        await _jobRepository.ChangeSyncStatus(JobStatusType.Finished);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, "Error occured during sync :(");
        await _jobRepository.ChangeSyncStatus(JobStatusType.Failed);
    }
}
```

Yet when I do this, I get an Exception with the message `Reset() called on connector with state Connecting`. I do not understand where this comes from.
 When I do not use the injected version, but instead do this:

```
using (var c = new JobTrackingContext())
{
    var job = new Job(jobType, jobTriggerType)
    await c.Jobs.AddAsync(job);
    await c.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

All seems to be working fine. It seems that the context gets disposed too early. But how can I prevent this and/or what am I missing?

The Full Stacktrace:

```
    System.ObjectDisposedException
  HResult=0x80131622
  Message=Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__52.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
   at ZShared.JobRepository.<StartSync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\richa\Documents\Codes\Company\Product\Shared\Folder\JobRepository.cs:line 38
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ZAccountSyncService.AccountSyncController.<Post>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\richa\Documents\Code\Company\Product\SubProduct\AccountSyncController.cs:line 32
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Comment: Where does `_dbContext` come from in your `JobRepository` code sample? It seems you have the whole class in the sample, but there is neither constructor nor a field called `_dbContext`...

Comment: It is saved in the superclass, which I have made more clearly now

Comment: Have you tried `.AddDbContext` instead of `.AddDbContextPool`? Does it work? What is your lifetime scope? What kind of application is it? ASP.NET (Core) or something different? Furthermore: Your last code sample might work because it lacks `await` when calling `.AddAsync` method. Does it work when you add the forgotten `await` there?

Comment: Yes I have tried changing it to `.AddDbContext`, and sadly that does not solve the issue. The lifetime scope of what? My `JobRepository` is scoped, as most of my classes are. And so is `JobTrackingContext`. It is a ASP.NETCORE application yes, and adding the  `await` does not break my other example.

Comment: ("scoped" means that you get one instance per scoped service inside a scope. How long is a scope depends on you - in ASP.NET Core, a scope is created per web request by default.) When do you get an exception? When calling `SaveChangesAsync`? Could you provide the whole stack trace?

Comment: Exactly, the exception happens at `SaveChangesAsync`. The scope is indeed created per web request. I added the stacktrace in my description. As you can see the whole error happens in code from the framework.

Comment: Could you try this: `services.AddTransient<IJobRepository, JobRepository>();`

Comment: Still the same error. I would wish for a way to control when `JobTrackingContext` gets deleted

Comment: Could you please post code of method `AccountSyncController.Post`?

Comment: I added the function, but I am afraid it won't add much extra info. I'm beginning to think that a) I am making a silly mistake b) It is really hard to spot

Comment: It added crucial info ;-) See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gist of the problem is the declaration of your `AccountSyncController.Post` method. You have `async void Post()` instead of `async Task Post()`.

When there is no task, a request has nothing to await and ends before the call of method `_sync.StartAsync()` is completed. With an end of a request comes also the end of a lifetime scope. On lifetime scoped end, all instances with scoped lifetime get disposed. Thus, your context is disposed before you get to the call of `SaveChanges` method. And this is the cause of your exception.

Comment: Thanks for helping with this problem and devoting as much time as you did